# Generar formulario dinámico con un botón

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Me gustaría saber como poder añadir campos como inputs o selects dinámicamente al hacer click en un botón.

```
                        <div class="inputs">
                            <div class="form-row" >
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <select data-width="130%" 
                                       id="producto" name="producto" data- 
                                       parsley-trigger="change" 
                                        class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Buscar</option>
                                        <option>Mustard</option>
                                        <option>Ketchup</option>
                                        <option>Relish</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                             <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input id="precio" type="text" 
                                     name="precio" data-parsley- 
                                     trigger="change"  autocomplete="off" 
                                     class="form-control" disabled>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light" 
                             name="agregar" type="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light">
                            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                        </button>
```

Lo que trato de hacer es que al dar en el botón de '+' me agregue un input y un select, la cuestión es que no he podido hacerlo y no encuentro la forma de añadir un input y un select con los estilos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Especifica mejor tu pregunta porque esto es lo que entiendo:
para hacerlo usa solo Javascript, HTML y CSS, no uses la extensión jQuery.

```
<head>
<style>
#text{
        display:none;border:2px solid #faaf88;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="f()">Formulario</button>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<script>
    function D(x){return document.getElementById(x);}

    var a=D("text"),c=0;
    function f() {
        if(c==0){
            a.style.display="block";
            c=1;
        }else{
            a.style.display="none";
            c=0;
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Uso Android.         Y me gustaría que en esta página agregaran soporte para la etiqueta <style>

Comment: No te estreses, aquí en la comunidad te ayudamos, deja encuentro un enlace de ayuda y te lo comparto, se bienvenido

Comment: Mira ya encontré el link de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) para formatear en tus respuestas, chécalo te será de mucho apoyo, éxitos y sigue aportando respuestas 

Comment: Muchas gracias.